# extracting specific information using web::scraper in perl

Tags: perl

I am new to web scraping. I was wondering if it is possible to extract specific information using `web::scraper` in perl. as an example, My html looks like follows(I took some part of html from URL):

```
 <table class="reference">
     <tr>
     <th width="23%" align="left">Property</th>
     <th width="71%" align="left">Description</th>
     <th style="text-align:center;">DOM</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_attributes.asp">attributes</a></td>
        <td>Returns a collection of a node's attributes</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_baseuri.asp">baseURI</a></td>
        <td>Returns the absolute base URI of a node</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_childnodes.asp">childNodes</a></td>
        <td>Returns a NodeList of child nodes for a node</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_firstchild.asp">firstChild</a></td>
        <td>Returns the first child of a node</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_lastchild.asp">lastChild</a></td>
        <td>Returns the last child of a node</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_localname.asp">localName</a></td>
        <td>Returns the local part of the name of a node</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_namespaceuri.asp">namespaceURI</a></td>
        <td>Returns the namespace URI of a node</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_nextsibling.asp">nextSibling</a></td>
        <td>Returns the next node at the same node tree level</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_nodename.asp">nodeName</a></td>
        <td>Returns the name of a node, depending on its type</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_nodetype.asp">nodeType</a></td>
        <td>Returns the type of a node</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_nodevalue.asp">nodeValue</a></td>
        <td>Sets or returns the value of a node, depending on its 
        type</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_ownerdocument.asp">ownerDocument</a></td>
        <td>Returns the root element (document object) for a node</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_parentnode.asp">parentNode</a></td>
        <td>Returns the parent node of a node</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_prefix.asp">prefix</a></td>
        <td>Sets or returns the namespace prefix of a node</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_previoussibling.asp">previousSibling</a></td>
        <td>Returns the previous node at the same node tree level</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="prop_node_textcontent.asp">textContent</a></td>
        <td>Sets or returns the textual content of a node and its 
        descendants</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">3</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

SO my perl code goes like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use URI;
use Web::Scraper;

# website to scrape
my $urlToScrape = "http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_node.asp";

my $rennersdata = scraper {
 process "table.reference > tr > td", 'landrenner[]' => 'TEXT';
 };

my $res = $teamsdata->scrape(URI->new($urlToScrape));
for my $i (0 .. $#{$res->{landrenner}}) {

print $res->{landrenner}[$i];
print "\n";
}
```

when I am running the above code, I get all the text inside `td` tag. i-e for `$i=0`, the output is:

```
attributes
Returns a collection of a node's attributes
1
```

Is it possible that I can only get the output:

```
Returns a collection of a node's attributes
```

What do I have to change in order to get the above output?

Answer (score 3):

Tell it you only want the second `td` by adjusting the CSS selector; instead of `"table.reference > tr > td"` do `"table.reference > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)"`

Comment: (After a little RTFS, I found that `nth-of-type` is way more efficient than `nth-child` in Web::Scraper due to the way it translates CSS to XPath.)

Comment: I was about to write up an `nth-child` solution, completely unaware of the performance implications. Great find!

Comment: Is it possible to have output like following from the above code:
`
<Name>attributes</Name>
<ReturnValue>Returns a collection of a node's attributes</ReturnValue>
<DOMVersion>1</DOMVersion>`

Comment: Is it possible to have output like following from the above code:


`<Name>attributes</Name> <ReturnValue>Returns a collection of a node's attributes</ReturnValue> <DOMVersion>1</DOMVersion>`