# perl module web::scraper

Tags: html, perl, web-scraping, perl-module

I want to extract the text only for heading Node Object Methods from a webpage. The specific html part is as follows:

```
<h2>Node Object Properties</h2>
<p>The &quot;DOM&quot; column indicates in which DOM Level the property was introduced.</p>

<table class="reference">
<tr>
<th width="23%" align="left">Property</th>
<th width="71%" align="left">Description</th>
<th style="text-align:center;">DOM</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_attributes.asp">attributes</a></td>
    <td>Returns a collection of a node's attributes</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_baseuri.asp">baseURI</a></td>
    <td>Returns the absolute base URI of a node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_childnodes.asp">childNodes</a></td>
    <td>Returns a NodeList of child nodes for a node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_firstchild.asp">firstChild</a></td>
    <td>Returns the first child of a node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_lastchild.asp">lastChild</a></td>
    <td>Returns the last child of a node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_localname.asp">localName</a></td>
    <td>Returns the local part of the name of a node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_namespaceuri.asp">namespaceURI</a></td>
    <td>Returns the namespace URI of a node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_nextsibling.asp">nextSibling</a></td>
    <td>Returns the next node at the same node tree level</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_nodename.asp">nodeName</a></td>
    <td>Returns the name of a node, depending on its type</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_nodetype.asp">nodeType</a></td>
    <td>Returns the type of a node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_nodevalue.asp">nodeValue</a></td>
    <td>Sets or returns the value of a node, depending on its 
    type</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_ownerdocument.asp">ownerDocument</a></td>
    <td>Returns the root element (document object) for a node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_parentnode.asp">parentNode</a></td>
    <td>Returns the parent node of a node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_prefix.asp">prefix</a></td>
    <td>Sets or returns the namespace prefix of a node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_previoussibling.asp">previousSibling</a></td>
    <td>Returns the previous node at the same node tree level</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="prop_node_textcontent.asp">textContent</a></td>
    <td>Sets or returns the textual content of a node and its 
    descendants</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">3</td>
</tr>
</table>

<h2>Node Object Methods</h2>
<p>The &quot;DOM&quot; column indicates in which DOM Level the method was introduced.</p>
<table class="reference">
<tr>
<th width="33%" align="left">Method</th>
<th width="61%" align="left">Description</th>
<th style="text-align:center;">DOM</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="met_node_appendchild.asp">appendChild()</a></td>
    <td>Adds a new child node, to the specified node, as the last child node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="met_node_clonenode.asp">cloneNode()</a></td>
    <td>Clones a node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="met_node_comparedocumentposition.asp">compareDocumentPosition()</a></td>
    <td>Compares the document position of two nodes</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>getFeature(<span class="parameter">feature</span>,<span class="parameter">version</span>)</td>
    <td>Returns a DOM object which implements the specialized APIs 
    of the specified feature and version</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">3 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>getUserData(<span class="parameter">key</span>)</td>
    <td>Returns the object associated to a key on a this node. The 
    object must first have been set to this node by calling setUserData with the 
    same key</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">3 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="met_node_hasattributes.asp">hasAttributes()</a></td>
    <td>Returns true if a node has any attributes, otherwise it 
    returns false</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="met_node_haschildnodes.asp">hasChildNodes()</a></td>
    <td>Returns true if a node has any child nodes, otherwise it 
    returns false</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="met_node_insertbefore.asp">insertBefore()</a></td>
    <td>Inserts a new child node before a specified, existing, child node</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In perl if I write the following:

```
 my $data = scraper {
 process "table.reference > tr > td > a", 'renners[]' => 'TEXT';
}

for my $i (0 .. $#{$res2->{renners}}) {
  print $res2->{renners}[$i];
print "\n";
}
```

I get the text for all the  tags i.e

```
attributes
baseURI
.
.
.
.
insertBefore()
```

wheras I need the text of tag  only for Node Object Methods i-e:

```
appendChild()
.
.
.
insertBefore()
```

What should I modify in the code? Kindly reply.

Comment: You've asked this same question and almost this same question [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618308/xml-output-from-html-page-using-web-scraping-in-perl) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634592/using-webscraper-in-perl) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617374/extracting-specific-information-using-webscraper-in-perl).  Please don't repost.

Comment: Instead, update your question with what you've learned, new ideas, and ask clarifying questions.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try matching the function parentheses from the extracted texts.

```
if ($res2->{renners}[$i] =~ m!\(\)$! ){
    print $res2->{renners}[$i],"\n"
}
```

This only works where the Node Object Functions are appended with parenthesis, ie the process call doesnt strip them out, and all the Functions (you require) are appended with parenthesis.

Comment: IS it possible to put heading 2 in condition like 
if("Node Object Methods") then print text

Comment: Yes, I think you need to look up matching operators a bit more. Most web scraping is matching of one kind or another. Though you seem to want to ask the object to recognise DOM Object methods per se. so read the synopsis of methods to see if it does that. hth.

Answer (score 0):

`process "table.reference > tr > td > a[contains(text(),'()')]"` should do it.

Comment: I got the error with this:
Invalid attribute-value selector '[contains(text(),'()')]'